# Fast Fourier Transform library from Exocortex.DSP

Tags: c#, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to use the FFT library from Exocortex.DSP.

The calling function is:

```
Exocortex.DSP.Fourier.FFT(float[], int, Exocortex.DSP.FourierDirection)
```

My line of code to use this function is:

```
Fourier.FFT(floatArray, arraycount, FourierDirection.Forward);
```

My program compiles, but why does it break at this line?

**The breaking window says:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in Exocortex.DSP.v1.dll
Additional information: Method not found: Log System.Math."*
```

Answer (score 0):

These sorts of errors happen when you compile your code against a library but then run against a different version, or if you compile only a sub-set of your solution's projects. What happens then is that the code attempts to call methods that don't exist or have a different signature in the assembly used at run-time.

Things I would check are:

- In the Build Configuration dialog, whether all the boxes are ticked/checked.
- Whether your projects are building to the directories you think they are.
- Whether you are actually running the built code or whether, somehow, you could be running old code from a different directory.
- Whether the library you are using is getting copied to the executable project's target directory correctly (if it's not it could suggest a dodgy reference somewhere in the solution).

Finally, it's possible that the library itself has been compiled against different versions of the libraries it uses. You may want to set up a small test project to make sure the library works correctly in a very simple test case before investigating why your existing project is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this is requiring a later version of the .NET framework (most likely 3.5 over 2.0, since 4.0 is a whole new framework again).

Check the installation requirements. Or use the mono Moma tool to see what referenced methods are missing.

No need to check the build config flags (it wouldn't run if it didn't complete compilation). However, it shouldn't compile if it has unresolveds. So perhaps you need to 'copy local' the referenced DLLs (not unlikely you are having different versions of that)

Also look inside the GAC for conflicting versions that could be picked up instead of the ones referenced during compilation

Comment: it most certainly is necessary to check the build config flags. If you build project A but not project B, and project B happens to call a method of project A, then it's possible to get exactly OP's exception if that method changes signature or is removed.

Comment: @paul: well if you want to be straightheaded you might be right in a way. Of course I meant that when the compilation succeeds at all, then there _must_ be a binary around that it compiled against. You should be able to run the resulting application against the same binary without any config changes. Of course, I'm assuming that the actual application is actively being built - thus giving the guarantee that compatible libs are accessible somehow

Comment: I tried the MoMA tool and no errors were found.
@paul: There are 2 boxes to check in the build config, build and deploy, both are checked.
*I am using VS 2008, do I need 2010 or something?
*Or, is there anywhere that I can download the missing reference (Log System.Math)?